# I am using Asp:FileUpload in Ajax updatePanel, Without updatePanel it is working fine but Giving Error with UpdatePanle

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload, asp-classic, updatepanel

I am using Asp:FileUpload in Ajax updatePanel, Without updatePanel it is working fine, Inserting my image into DataBase but with UpdatePanel it is Giving Error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" class="buttonGeneral" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

this is Where Error is.

```
string filePath = FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName;
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?&q=fileupload%20updatepanel

Comment: Thanks Yuriy Galanter :) I thought the problem is in my code. Your answer Helped.

Comment: no problem. But do try googling your problem before posting question here. Chances are someone else experienced it before and found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to Use a PostBack Trigger

https://www.google.com/search?&q=fileupload%20updatepanel